React + Express: Mixed Content The page at was loaded over HTTPS but requested an insecure resource
I'm running an express server on a DigtalOcean droplet on port 3000 and I can access that server in Postman on https://my-id-adress:300/hi but when I try to call this API in my React project I get this error Mixed Content The page at was loaded over HTTPS but requested an insecure resource This request has been blocked the content must be served over HTTPS
How can I fix this issue? My React app is deployed on Vercel and I don't have a custom domain name.

The error suggests it wasn't https.

@Evert yes, its http and I don't have a custom domain

Can't I just send request with http only without buying a custom domain ?

Unfortunately as far as I know you need a domainname to get a free SSL certificate. However, there's definitely hosts out there that have a free tier and give you some subdomain for free that can be encrypted. I don't have a recommendation for this.

share your package.json file here

@AnilSingha package.json file of server or client?

both will be better @wdwd

@AnilSingha well both are very basic can you tell which field you want to look?

https,http  this two I hope you already have this @wdwd

@AnilSingha No, I don't have this, I have a Next.js client and express server

It seems there is no way from backend to get this issue - "Mixed Content..." , resolved.
However there are some workarounds from backend.  Please see the discussion over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62755017/is-there-some-workaround-i-can-use-to-avoid-mixed-content-errors
